# Angular directive does not evaluate simple expression when using the & operator

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive with an isolate scope configured like so:

```
  scope: {
    title: '@',
    icon: '@',
    onSelect: '&'
  },
```

When I provide a simple expression like:

```
<my-component on-select="alert('test')"></my-component>
```

The expression is not evaluated (does not fire).

However, the following does work:

```
<my-component on-select="vm.someValue = true"></my-component>
```

And if I move my simple `alert` call into a function in my controller and pass that, it also works:

```
<my-component on-select="vm.sendAlert()"></my-component>
```

The behaviour seems a bit inconsistent. Can someone explain the requirements of expression bindings?

Comment: Have you defined a $scope.alert() function? All expressions are always evaluated on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by JB Nizet, expressions inside of an angular binding are evaluated on scope.

> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.

Therefore angular only allows you to use simple operators and functions on scope inside of bindings.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a function into a directive as a parameter such that the directive can call it, this is the best way I've found to get it to work.

```
$scope.myfunction = function(msg) {  alert(msg); }

<my-component on-select="myfunction"/>
```

Directive:

```
  scope : {  onSelect: '=' }  // Notice using '='

  scope.doCall = function() {  onSelect("some message");  }  // Call the passed in function
```